# how to stop sharing a calendar in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I once shared a calendar on icalx.com from Outlook 2010.

I do not want to share it anymore and I get constant pop-ups from Outlook requesting me to provide a login / password to access icalx.com (which is very annoying).

How can I "unshare" a calendar so that Outlooks stops prompting me?

(I looked through everything I could find by right-clicking on the calendar without success)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It was hidden in `File -> Account Settings -> Published Calendars`

Comment: I did try after finding the answer but I need to wait two days to be allowed to do so

Comment: Apologies, forgot about that.